# Why does Windows 10 move desktop files to the recycling bin?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, recycle-bin

I set up a [family account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/17199/windows-10-set-up-your-family) for my daughter on [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10). She wrote a bunch of Word files and saved them on the desktop.

The following day they were all missing. We found them in the recycle bin.

This [seems to be](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/13060-desktop-icons-have-disappeared.html) a pattern [online](http://forums.windowscentral.com/onedrive/374097-beware-onedrive-keeps-moving-files-recycle-bin-itself.html) - but no one seems to have an explanation.

My question is: **Why does Windows 10 move desktop files to the recycling bin?**

Comment: "Why does Windows 10 move desktop files to the recycling bin?" - It doesn't, at least not automatically, it sounds like somebody (a human) deleted the files.

Comment: No OSes does that stupid thing. There must be some people or programs (like virus) which have done that. And avoid putting things on desktop as much as possible

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - that's helpful. I challenge your assertion because it appears that other people have this problem online - as evidenced by the two linked resources. Did you read them?

Comment: @hawkeye - I read them.  I don't trust people's conclusions when they say, Windows deletes files, there is normally something else going on.

Comment: @hawkeye The first link does not mention the recycle bin at all. I glanced at it quickly but the thread is **marked as solved** and involved other issues (like not showing the desktop icons). The second link is about OneDrive deleting the files. So not Windows 10 but additional software. Do you have OneDrive. Is the desktop maybe set as OneDrive-directory?